# In iPhone App ,How to add tab bar controller on some particular view controller Programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uitabbarcontroller

In iPhone App ,How to add tab bar controller on some particular view controller Programmatically?
Here the viewcontroller Class is  is UITableviewcontroller .

right now if i am adding the tab bar it appears  some where in table view. i want to display  it on bottom of window and and tableview should scroll separately from Tabbarcontroller

Please help and suggest

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
    FirstView *view1 = [[FirstView alloc]init];
    SecondView *view2 = [[SecondView alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *firstview = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:view1];
    UINavigationController *secondview = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:view2];
    UITabBarController* tabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    [tabBar setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:view1, view2, nil]];
    [tabBar setDelegate:self];
    UINavigationController* navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tabBar];
    [self.view addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

Try this. here FirstView, SecondView are the class. if you click the tab, corresponding class (view) will open. And you have declare the tabbar and navigation controller delegate.

Comment: thanks, by this code I could add it programmatically and tab bar appears but the problem it is scrolling with table view and my  main view controller class is uitableviewcontroller so how caan i fixthe position of tab bar and  make table view scroll separatelly.

Comment: Try this:  `[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];`

Answer (score 1):

first you just select tabbar base application from project template.

now double click on mainwindow.xib its open it in interface builder.

now click on tabbarcontroller and open inspector window.

[image]

in above image your are able to see list of viewcontrollers. click on  class tab will gives you the option of controller type. see in below image

[image]

if your are selecting table view controller then your first controller is table view. and tabbar is not in your view. table is scroll separately.

Comment: I want to add it programmatically and the problem is that it is scrolling with tableview

Answer (score -1):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];


    //************   WRITE THE CODE OVER HERE FOR THE CREATION OF THE TAB BAR BY CODING**************

    tabbar_object=[[UITabBarController alloc] init];


    self.tabbarViewController=[[[TabBarViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TabBarViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

    self.viewcontroller1=[[[FirstViewControllerForTabBar alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewControllerForTabBar" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.viewcontroller2=[[[SecondViewControllerForTabBar alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewControllerForTabBar" bundle:nil] autorelease];

    UINavigationController *tabbatnavigation=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tabbarViewController];
    tabbatnavigation.title=@"First Tab";
    UINavigationController *navigation1=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewcontroller1];
    navigation1.title=@"Sign Up";
    UINavigationController *navigation2=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewcontroller2];
    navigation2.title=@"Sign Out";
    tabbar_object.viewControllers=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:navigation1,navigation2,tabbatnavigation, nil];
    [tabbar_object setSelectedIndex:0];

    //************************************************************************************************



    self.window.rootViewController = tabbar_object;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```